# Sorting <li> elements by nested hidden input values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, dom

example DOM:

```
<ul class="children">
     <li class="child_container" rel="1803">
         <input type="hidden" name="content_child_meta[1803][sort_order]" value="2">
     </li>
     <li class="child_container" rel="2843">
         <input type="hidden" name="content_child_meta[2843][sort_order]" value="1">
     </li>
     <li class="child_container" rel="3803">
         <input type="hidden" name="content_child_meta[3803][sort_order]" value="3">
     </li>
</ul>
```

Trying to sort on <\li> using values in nested inputs.

Did try following:

```
var child_container = jQuery("ul");
child_container.find("li.child_container").sort(function (a, b) {
                return +a.find("input[name$='[sort_order]']").val() - +b.find("input[name$='[sort_order]']").val();
            })
            .appendTo( child_container );
```

and few other variations of this, but no luck on this guys getting in line..

Any help?

Comment: `a` and `b` are not jQuery object : http://jsfiddle.net/k23hjema/

Comment: Do you need to use hidden inputs? Why not use data attributes like : `<li class="child_container" data-child-id="1803" data-child-sort-order="2">`

Comment: I can't, this structure is already set..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
$(".children li").sort(sort_li).appendTo('.children');
function sort_li(a, b){
   return (parseInt($(b).find('input').val(), 10)) < (parseInt($(a).find('input').val(), 10)) ? 1 : -1;    
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9tm60ba5/)**

Comment: This may give odd results when you have more than one element that matches the `.children` selector.

Answer (score 2):

Because jQuery is a kind of array, [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) will work just fine on it; once sorted, you can push those elements back into the parent.

Altogether it would look like this:

```js
$(".children").append(function() {
    return $(this).children().sort(function(a, b) {
        return $('input', a).val() - $('input', b).val();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="children">
     <li class="child_container" rel="1803">
         <input type="hidden" name="content_child_meta[1803][sort_order]" value="2">
     </li>
     <li class="child_container" rel="2843">
         <input type="hidden" name="content_child_meta[2843][sort_order]" value="1">
     </li>
     <li class="child_container" rel="3803">
         <input type="hidden" name="content_child_meta[3803][sort_order]" value="3">
     </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Interesting solution to selecting. How did you made this run code snippet?

Comment: @SubjectX In the edit section of your post you can choose to add "code snippet" with Ctrl-M.

Comment: @SubjectX Ah, `$('input', a)` is equivalent to `$(a).find('input')` ... the former is shorter :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
  $('#order').click(function(){    
    var sorted =$('.children').find('input:hidden').sort(function(a,b){ 
      return parseInt(a.value)- parseInt(b.value)
    });  
    for(var i=0;i<=sorted.length;i++){
      $('.children').append($(sorted[i]).parent('li'));
    }    
  });
});`
```